# Cakephp-Querying models according to context

Tags: php, cakephp, dynamic, model

I need to do something like this.

```
$model="MyModel";
$results=$this->"MyModel"->find("all);
```

so I need to call a different function according to the case. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you're trying to do is call a different Model according to conditions right?

```
$model = "Model";
$results = $this->{$model}->find('all');
```

However, if you find yourself needing to do this, it might be due to organizing your code incorrectly. You might want to look into alternatives.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. 
I know it looks weird and "dirty" but it's the only solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that from within the controller action

```
class MyControllerController extends AppController
{
    function action_name()
    {
        $this->uses = array(
            'MyModel',
            'AnotherModel'
        );

        $this->AnotherModel->find('all');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$model = "Model";
$results = $this->{$model}->find('all');

Using this approach is ok in accordance to CakePHP coding conventions and has no better or cleaner alternatives. Especially when you are coding behaviors with complex logic. So stick to it and don't worry.